# MultiDex Support

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-multidex

My app is crashing due to multidex. Below is the crash log information :

> 12-23 16:43:12.437 6823-6823/com.rogers.tsc I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
>       12-23 16:43:12.438 6823-6823/com.rogers.tsc I/MultiDex: install
>       12-23 16:43:12.438 6823-6823/com.rogers.tsc I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
>       12-23 16:43:12.462 6823-6823/com.rogers.tsc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       12-23 16:43:12.463 6823-6823/com.rogers.tsc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.rogers.tsc, PID: 6823
>                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
>                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzz(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
>                                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

It seems there is some problem with the multidex which is causing the issue. I have already added the multidex support to my application. I also have added  `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` to my app gradle.

Here is my **application class**

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static TscApplication mApplication;
public static TscApplication getApplication()
{
    return mApplication;
}

public Context getApplicationContext(){

    return mApplication;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mApplication = this;

}
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

Whenever I add application class reference in AndroidManifest then only crash is occurring otherwise not if I remove it.

Below is my **app.graddle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.ysc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just do `public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {`

Comment: You don't need to extends any class with Application class. Just Enable multidex in app gradle.
multiDexEnabled = true

Answer (score 2):

basically this is caused because you exceed the limits of method.you have two options for solve this error .

1)Decrease the no of methods in your project .Basically the library you added in your projects methods also count in your project methods. so don't use whole package of that library use the module that you uses in your project:For example Google play services you added whole package add the module you want to use like map etc..

2)Second one Enable the multidex for enable multidex : Now, all you need to do is override this in your Application class

```
public class YouApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

Add multidex support library in your gradal

```
  android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
     targetSdkVersion 22

     // Enabling multidex support.
     multiDexEnabled true
    }
    }

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
...
android:name="YouApplication">
...
</application>
```

I hope this will Help you....

Comment: you either use multidex install in on attachBaseContext method or extend MultidexApplication using both are pointless as both do the same